# Trying to get property of non object when iterating through the children node

Tags: php, xml

I am getting an error when trying to extract the data from xml in a loop.

Here is what i get when i dd($Listing->Photos)

[image]

```
$Photos = $Listing->Photos;

$i = 0;
while ($Photo = $Photos->children())
{
    $listingPhoto = new ListingPhoto;
    $listingPhoto->mediaURL = $Photo[$i]->MediaURL;
    $listingPhoto->save();
    $i++;
}
```

It does save some of the MediaURL photos but after saving few photos it throw an error ..
maybe it tries to run to throw another parent node then it looks for child node MediaURL and it doesn't find this and throws an error?

```
Trying to get property 'MediaURL' of non-object
```

**Updated:**
Is there any better approach to do this, i realized my while loop is running forever that's why i am getting an error cause it doesn't find MediaURL

Answer (score 0):

it's because after a few iteration, this one $Photo[$i]->MediaURL return null or empty that's why it return an error of like that. Check it first if it has a return

```
$listingPhoto = new ListingPhoto;
$listingPhoto->mediaURL = isset($Photo[$i]->MediaURL) ? $Photo[$i]->MediaURL : '';
$listingPhoto->save();
```

Comment: I removed the MediaURL and instead i put $i++ to see why it was failing, i realized for some reason my while loop is running infinite times..

Comment: can you just initialize this variable $Photo = $Photos->children() outside of the loop.

Comment: same issue running forever

Comment: what's the return of $photos->children() ?

Comment: Trying to get property 'MediaUrl' of non-object

Comment: can you just do it like this ?

 foreach ($Photos as $key => $photo) {
         $listingPhoto = new ListingPhoto;
         $listingPhoto->mediaURL = $photo['MediaUrl'];
      $listingPhoto->save();
  }

Comment: I tried like this with foreach , however i didn't get any error this time .. but the value of MediaURL is empty for some reason. it didn't save anything.. i tried as ->MediaURL and also ['MediaURL'] but didn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206166/discussion-between-qonvex620-and-learning-php-oop).

Comment: Thank you i see it working fine with foreach however i had to this foreach ($Listing->Photos as $key => $Photos) {
                                            $listingPhoto->mediaURL = $Photos->Photo['MediaURL'];

}

Comment: But it will still save the same mediaURL I guess. Maybe this one will work
 $listingPhoto->mediaUR=  $Photos[$key]->Photo['MediaURL']

Comment: Still having the problems, without the children() method, it doesn't loop through, it goes for the first time and gets out of it.. doesn't go for the second time.

Comment: what's the return of children() ?

Comment: children() make it possible to loop through and get the photos however it run over when there are no longer nodes available.